# Problem exporting-importing table

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of table on my Database MySql :

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`surname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`nickname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`mail` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`country` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`birthday` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
`accessres` TINYINT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`admin` TINYINT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`datereg` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`forum_ban` TINYINT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`last_access` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=209
```

How you can see, collate is utf8_general_ci. The problem is when I export-import this table using HeidiSQL (6.0)-phpMYADMIN.

For example, if I have data such as `Krüger`, it is exported-imported as `KrÃ¼ger`! 
My whole application is on `utf8`, so on DB `Krüger` is really written as `Krüger`.

So there are some wrong in the export. What can I do? I think the problem is phpMyAdmin, because if I try to import the table again on HeidiSQL, the text are correct.

Comment: As far as I know HeidiSQL does a proper uft8 handling when selected. How did you validate that export? Is it possible the program you're viewing the export with can't cope with utf8? If viewing such an export with an older software, a proper coded special character it might actually show like the example you've provided.

Comment: I'm using Scite Text Editor...! In fact if I import again on HeidiSQL, the strings are correct :O

Comment: Again... how did you validate that export? The german `ü` is actually coded as `C3 BC` in utf8, which would be interpreted as `Ã¼` by not utf8-supporting viewers (or viewers not configured to show it as utf8!). If your export shows `C3 BC` (try using a HEX Editor for this) on this position, the export ain't broken, but something else is.

Comment: With `XVI32` I see `Ã=C3`, `¼=BC`... but why? Why Hex Editor show to me `Ã¼` instead of `ü`?

Comment: That means that the export is ok and you needn't worry about the export. In utf8 the german `ü` is coded `C3 BC` - and a proper Viewer can show it in both encodings. The export ain't your problem, the import is. Make sure you've selected utf8 in the import options of your phpmyadmin. I've just tried it with an older version of phpmyadmin, works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But where can I select this options on phpMyAdmin? :)

Comment: I've lost a bit track on phpmyadmin, but all of these options used to be in the screen where the import takes place. There should be options regarding file encoding (utf8, latin1, ascii,..., this is where you have to select utf8), the type of file (csv, xml, ...) you're using, and a few different options, too. Maybe they've changed the position of the screen in later releases than I am using, but it should be there somewhere.

Comment: Done! I wrong, because I usually don't use the import interface, but just the copy/paste SQL. No more from today :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the issue when you open the exported file or import it back into a database. If you are seeing the error when importing with phpMyAdmin, you might need to import via the command line and use the flag.

```
--default-character-set=utf8
```

Ive run into these issues as well and importing via the command line and using this flag has worked.

If you have a file exported from phpMyAdmin, you can import it by doing this on the command line.

```
mysql -u USER -p DATABASENAME --default-character-set=utf8 < dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: Yes the problem is when I import on phpMYADMIN. Can you be more specific as "command line" ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem only happens when you export the database through phpMYAdmin and import database through mysql command line or vice versa. You either export or import through phpMyAdmin or through command line and you will not face the problem

Comment: Its the same thing buddy or you while importing through command line also add --default-character-set=utf8 then there will be no problem.

Comment: They are using the same thing on import and export and that's why no problem and if you go from plugin to command line it will cause problem or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLyog MySQL GUI software.

Answer (score 1):

try not use any mysql GUI clients/web interface,
[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) , [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) is more than what you need

if you insists,
check on the encoding setting on HeidiSQL clients to make sure is set to UTF-8